# When asked to find all solutions to a differential equation, what's left implicit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

Suppose the following problem were to appear in an introductory textbook on differential equations.

> Find all solutions to $y'=y$.

What's left implicit in such a statement? My interpretation of the problem would be:

Find the set of all differentiable functions $y : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. For all $x \in X$ it holds that $y'(x) = y(x)$
2. $X$ is connected.
3. No function with properties (1) and (2) is a proper extension of $y$.

Edit: An alternative opinion was advanced in the comments, that the problem is to find the set of all differentiable functions $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $y'(x) = y(x).$

Comment: I think, unless otherwise specified, the real problem is usually $X=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that "$X$ is connected" is the same thing as "$X$ is an interval".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is $[a,\infty)$ considered an interval?

Comment: I consider it to be an interval --- a semi-infinite interval. But I take your point.

Comment: I also consider it to be an interval; but I just thought it would be less confusing to call it "connected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, finding the largest X is part of the problem. For example with linear DE where coefficients are functions with discontinuities.

Sometimes you have two sets of solutions on intervals $]-\infty, a[$ and $]a,+\infty[$, and you have to find solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ : there may be infinitely many, only some, or none, depending on cases.

You may also have to look for [singular solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution).